# dojo dojox.image.SlideShow could not be loaded

Tags: image, constructor, slideshow, dojo

I want to use the dojox.image.SlideShow in a dialog but I can't get it to work. He keeps giving me errors like

```
 'it's no constructor'.
```

I use dojo 1.7 and the AMD loader.
Could anybody give me tips or an example?

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 0):

The `>>built` versions of the image.Slideshow fails through AMD loader, replace these with a -src checkout:

http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojox/trunk/image/ThumbnailPicker.js

http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/dojox/trunk/image/SlideShow.js

So, download the 1.7-src snapshot or (for time being 1.7.2 is HEAD) download from the above  links. Extract / copy the files 'dojo/dojox/image/SlideShow.js' and 'dojo/dojox/image/ThumbnailPicker.js' and overwrite the existing ones in your dojotree.